# programe run certain period of time using thread () and subprocess()

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, subprocess, python-multithreading

I want to run multiple commands on my liunx os so I create a script to run multiple commands but some command take too much time to execute but I want terminate the commands which take more then 1 min to execute.
How can i do that?

```
import subprocess
import threading
import time
from time import sleep

def prog(line):
    def worker(line):
        print(line)
        subprocess.call(line, shell=True )

    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(line,))
    t.start()
    
f=open("a",'r')
for line in f:
    prog(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.call` has a `timeout` parameter.
It kills the command after a given timout (in seconds) and raises `TimeoutExpired`.

```py
import subprocess
import threading

def prog(line):
    def worker(line):
        print(line)
        try:
            subprocess.call(line, shell=True, timeout=60)
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as e:
            print(e)

    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(line,))
    t.start()
    
f=open("a",'r')
for line in f:
    prog(line)
```

Here a runnable minimal example: https://ideone.com/ZToaJU

---

Another hint, while not asked for: you don't need to pass `args=(line,)` to the worker function. As it is declared as a nested function, it already has access to the `line` variable of `prog`:

```
import subprocess
import threading

def prog(line):
    def worker():
        print(line)
        try:
            subprocess.call(line, shell=True, timeout=60)
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as e:
            print(e)

    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t.start()
    
f=open("a",'r')
for line in f:
    prog(line)
```

Comment: that's not a very detailed error description.

Comment: i want to run this kind of command but is show error

Comment: You still didn't say what the error is. I'm sorry, but it would be really helpful if you give SOME information.

Comment: Just look at your own comment: "python ss.py -u url.target".
I don't know what 'ss.py' is, I don't know why you add "-u", what "url.target" is supposed to be nor what the error message says. How am I supposed to help you?

Comment: some script was already written by someone but I don't want o change anything in the script but I want to run that script automatically through another python file.

Comment: If "a" is a python script then your approach of executing it line by line is completely wrong. It should be run as the entire script.

Comment: Otherwise, I cannot help you with the information you give me. Please provide a minimal reproducible example. If you don't, I'd end the discussion here.